# How to get panel within vbox layout to fill container?

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, panel

I'm having trouble getting a panel to fill the space within its container panel. The container is a panel with a vbox layout having two child panels. I looked at [Extjs how to set 100% height for vbox panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770207/extjs-how-to-set-100-height-for-vbox-panel) 
and have something similar but it doesn't seem to work.

Screenshots:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mZ5G.png
The screenshot is from when i use a 'fit' layout or dont even have the combobox or optionsview in a containing panel. So, what i want is for the 'options' panel to extend all the way down till the 'results' panel.
with the present vbox layout this is what i get - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vInp.png

```
Ext.define('PA.view.CreateReportView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.createreportview',
    id: 'createreport-panel',
    requires: [
        'PA.view.OptionsView', // options panel
    'PA.common.Connection'],

    title: 'Create Report',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: false,
            height: '50px',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                ....
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: false,
            flex: 1,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'optionsview', // options panel
                style: {
                    paddingTop: '10px'
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `height:` should be a number, not a string. So use `height: 50` instead.

Comment: Then I guess it's because your outer 'Create Report' panel has no layout specified. You should give it `layout: 'fit'`. Or remove the extra panel component completely.

Comment: Setting the layout to fit in createpanel and the panel containing optiopnsview fixed it.It works perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have it close to what you need. Couple of observations:
1. Heights need to be set as integers (no px suffix)
2. Each container that will have children should have a layout defined for them, even though there is default - it might not be what you want.

Here is your layout working reasonably well http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/NJjhB/

One other suggestion I would add is to use a tool like Illuminations for Developers - a firebug plugin that knows about ExtJS framework.

Comment: Thanks! this does seem to work however the combobox also extends all the way to the right of the page. I have specified a specific width for it but i guess the layout overides it. Any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: That's the align:stretch coming into play. If you need to isolate combo from that config you may need to wrap it into a container which will stretch but give it a different layout for its children [combobox] - what ever makes sense.

Comment: One other comment I wanted to make about your layouts is to be careful striking the balmce between getting the layout you need and over-nesting panels. Over-nesting carries performance penalties.